# Where to put makefile flags in a Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

In the makefile:

```
 CUSTOM_CFLAGS=-Wall -ggdb3 -O3 -std=gnu99 -frename-registers -pthread -Wsign-compare -D_GNU_SOURCE

 SYS_CFLAGS=-DNO_THREAD_LOCAL
 LDFLAGS=-pthread -rdynamic
 LIBS=-lm -ldl
```

Where should I put the above in Xcode project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makefile flags correspond to Xcode build settings. Look into the following build settings:

Optimization Level for the -O3 flag. 
C Language Dialect for the -std=gnu99 flag. 
Other C Flags for the other flags in the CUSTOM_CFLAGS and SYS_CFLAGS flags. 
Other Linker Flags for the LDFLAGS and LIBS flags.

Xcode may have build settings for some of the flags in the makefile's CUSTOM_CFLAGS flag list and the linker flags. I haven't memorized the build settings list. If you open the Quick Help inspector, you can read a description of each build setting by selecting the build setting from the build settings list. Choose View > Utilities > Show Quick Help Inspector to show the Quick Help inspector.

If you don't know where to find Xcode's build settings, read the following article:

[Xcode 4: Accessing Build Settings](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/03/xcode-4-accessing-build-settings/)

Answer (score 1):

When building a Makefile-based project with Xcode using the "External Build System" template

[image: Xcode template for 'External Build System']

…you can add any necessary environment variables such as CFLAGS or LDFLAGS to the build settings for the project, as shown below:

[image: Adding CFLAGS/LDFLAGS environment variables to an Xcode project]

These values are then exported as environment variables during the build process, which `make` and the Makefile will pick up on, assuming your Makefile has, for example, something like this inside it:

```
CXXFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -std=c++11

g++ $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp
```

This is what I needed to do to build a Makefile-based project that depended on the GNU Scientific Library, using the `gsl` package from Macports, which puts everything in `/opt/local` instead of the "standard" places where Xcode looks for shared libraries and headers.

Maybe this can help somebody else in this situation.